# Create MultiBinding label at runtime

Tags: xamarin, binding, runtime, multibinding

I have the following xaml,a collectionView, that works fine and multidatabinds a label.

```
<Label TextType="Html">
    <Label.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}{2}">
            <Binding Path="ItemArray[1]" />
            <Binding Path="ItemArray[2]" />
            <Binding Path="ItemArray[3]" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.Text>
</Label>
```

I want exactly the same thing but i want to create the DataTemplate of the collectionView at runtime.
So create the Label at runtime and set the multidatabind at runtime.
Is it possible?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What is the issue with putting this into a DataTemplate? Do you mean that the binding path will change for each of the items you will try to bind? What about just exposing a property in your ViewModel which does this formatting for you? That is the purpose of a ViewModel anyways, to prepare and format data to be displayed in a View.

Comment: The datasource of the collectionview is abstact. I am getting data from a webservice and do not know what data i will get (items, customers or something else). When i get all the data i create a datatable that is the datasource of the collectionview. Then I create the datatemplate of the colectionview at runtime and i want to create a label that is multibound to the datatable.

Comment: To create the DataTemplate of the collectionView, you could try the following code:`BindingContext = new CustomViewModel();
CollectionView collectionView = new CollectionView();
collectionView.SetBinding(ItemsView.ItemsSourceProperty, "Monkeys");
collectionView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
{
    ...
});`. But for setting MultiBinding for Label, there seems something wrong with the function. For normal data binding, just use the `label.SetBinding(Label.TextTypeProperty, multiBinding);` command.

Comment: It doesn't work for MultiBinding, which may be a potential issue. You coud report it to the product team on github for a solution. github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/new/choose